# Re-Sizing Hash Table

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, resize, hashtable

I'm attempting to resize my `hash table` however; I am keep getting a `NullPointerException`.
I know if the size is greater than `0.75` then the table size has to double, if it's less than `0.50` then the table size is halved. So far I have this..

```
public boolean add(Object x)
{
  int h = x.hashCode();
  if (h < 0) { h = -h; }
  h = h % buckets.length;

  Node current = buckets[h];
  while (current != null)
  {
     if (current.data.equals(x)) { return false; }
        // Already in the set
     current = current.next;
  }
  Node newNode = new Node();
  newNode.data = x;
  newNode.next = buckets[h];
  buckets[h] = newNode;
  currentSize++;
  double factor1 = currentSize * load1; //load1 = 0.75
  double factor2 = currentSize * load2; //load2 = 0.50
  if (currentSize > factor1) { resize(buckets.length*2); }
  if (currentSize < factor2) { resize(buckets.length/2); }

  return true;
}
```

Example. `Size = 3. Max Size = 5` 
if we take the `Max Size` and multiply by `0.75` we get `3.75`. 
this is the factor that says if we pass it the `Max Size` must `double` 
so if we add an extra `element` into the `table` the size is `4` and is `> 3.75` thus the new `Max Size` is `10`. 
However; once we increase the size, the `hashcode` will change with the addition of a new `element`, so we call `resize(int newSize)`

```
private void resize(int newLength)
{
  //   
   HashSet newTable = new HashSet(newLength);

   for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++) {
       newTable.add(buckets[i]);
   }
}
```

Here is my constructor if the `buckets[i]` confuses anyone.

```
public HashSet(int bucketsLength)
{
  buckets = new Node[bucketsLength];
  currentSize = 0;
}
```

I feel that the logic is correct, unless my `resize` method is not retrieving the `elements`.

Comment: Post your stack trace and note which line it's referring to.

Comment: I'm confused.  If you have 4 entries, and you've just resized to 10 (because 4 exceeds 75% of 5), don't you now have to resize to 5, since 4 is less than 50% of 10?  To avoid this situation, I think the lower threshold percentage needs to be less than half the higher threshold percentage.  So 30% and 75% would probably work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is all your code for `resize()`, then you are failing to assign `newTable` to a class attribute, i.e. your old table. Right now you fill it with data and then don't do anything with it, since it is defined inside `resize` and therefore not available outside of it.

So you end up thinking you have a larger table now, but in fact you are still using the old one ;-)

Comment: This makes sense, so I have to assign the new table to the old table?